# Filter dataframe on non-empty WrappedArray

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My problem is that I have to find in a list, these which are not empty. When I use the filter function is not null, than I get also every row.

My program code looks like this:

```
...    
val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
val df = csc.sql("SELECT * FROM test").toDF()

val wrapped = df.select("fahrspur_liste")
wrapped.printSchema
```

The column `fahrspur_liste` contains the wrapped arrays and this column I have to analyze. When I run the code, than I get this structure for my wrapped array and these entries:

```
    root
 |-- fahrspur_liste: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

+--------------+
|fahrspur_liste|
+--------------+
|            []|
|            []|
|          [56]|
|            []|
|          [36]|
|            []|
|            []|
|          [34]|
|            []|
|            []|
|            []|
|            []|
|            []|
|            []|
|            []|
|         [103]|
|            []|
|         [136]|
|            []|
|          [77]|
+--------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Now I want to filter these rows, so that I have only the entries [56],[36],[34],[103], ...

How can I write a filter function, that I get only these rows, which contains a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an `udf` in Spark:

```
val removeEmpty = udf((array: Seq[Long]) => !array.isEmpty)

val df2 = df.filter(removeEmpty($"fahrspur_liste"))
```

Here the `udf` checks if the array is empty or not. The filter function will then remove those that come back as true.

Answer (score 18):

I don't think you need to use a UDF here.

You can just use [`size`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#size(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) method and filter all those rows with array size = 0

```
df.filter(""" size(fahrspur_liste) != 0 """)
```

Comment: in pyspark: `from pyspark.sql.functions import size`